# How to update connected BLE device's firmware with IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, firmware

Is it possible to update BLE device firmware with iOS app? I have BLE device's firmware file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Using iOSDFULibrary.

Link : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-Pods-DFU-Library

Nordic have there app too if you just want to update outside of your app : nRF Connect